# Trying to install pyautogui and cannot find pip3 to do so

Tags: terminal, python

pip command works, but the instructions say to use pip3.
Upon checking the version of python I have with:

```
$pip --version
```

I get:

```
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Shouldn't that be pip3 if I am using Python 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

Pip comes installed with python 2.7 pip3 is the python 3.6 version of pip. Try pip3 --version it will return the same pip 9.0.1.

Comment: I get this:
$pip3 --version
-bash: pip3: command not found

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993086/pip3-command-not-found-but-python3-pip-is-already-installed

Comment: I got this: WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Which I ran, then later > locate pip3 and it just goes to cursor prompt like nothing happened.

Comment: try using python3 -m pip this instead of pip3 if this doesnt work then uninstall and reinstall pip3

Comment: Thanks. That worked.  Then I was able to see it was downloadable through Anaconda with conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui.
Thanks again.